# React native firebase navigation after sucess

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, navigation, native

Since a few days I can not redirect after login with react navigation, can someone give me a hint?

My code :

```
loginUser = (email, password) => {

    try{
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {

            // NAVIGATION ACTION ***

  })
    }
    catch(error){
        alert("Login Failed!");
    }

}
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: because I can not find the solution !

Comment: The `user` variable will be `null` if not signed in, so if it is not `null` you can redirect to whatever page you want.

Comment: thank u very @ColinRicardo !! nice

Comment: No worries, please mark my answer as correct if it helped. Thanks!

Comment: if (user != null) {
    console.log("We are authenticated now!");
  }

Answer (score 0):

The `user` variable will be `null` if not signed in, so if it is not `null` you can redirect to whatever page you want.